# Disable hyphenation in Metropolis' frametitles

Tags: beamer, hyphenation, frame-title, beamer-metropolis

How do I disable hyphenation in in the otherwise very nice Beamer theme [Metropolis](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-metropolis)? I have tried looking through all of Metropolis' code relating to the frametitle, but I can't figure out what triggers them to be hyphenated when frametitles in the default theme aren't---except that the cause lies in Metropolis' outer theme. Help is much appreciated!

Below is my minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hyphenated frametitle in the Metropolis theme]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly metropolis use the same value for the left and the right margin, so one imho has to rewrite the template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{newplain}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperwidth,%
      sep=0pt,%
      leftskip=\metropolis@frametitle@padding,%
      rightskip=\the\glueexpr \metropolis@frametitle@padding plus 1fill\relax,%
    ]{frametitle}%
  \metropolis@frametitlestrut@start%
  \insertframetitle%
  \nolinebreak%
  \metropolis@frametitlestrut@end%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation
     hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation
     hyphenation hyphenation}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\raggedright` ideally by adding that to the frame title setting in the theme but as a one off you can add it to the document

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{{\raggedright Hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation
     hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation
     hyphenation hyphenation\endgraf}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\noindent}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: where is the left margin gone?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer into the depths of beamer, where few fear to tread.